# Can we claim that the probability $(2)$ is always less and equal to $(1)$ when events are dependent, and independent?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two functions $f$ and $g$. I consider the positivity of these functions as two events $A$ and $B$

- $P(A)=P(f>0)$
- $P(B)=P(g>0)$

I want to calculate the probability that product of the functions is positive, $P(f.g>0)$ for both cases when the events $A,B$ are **dependent** and **independent**. The product $f.g$ is positive if both functions are positive, or negative (disjoint events).

> If events are **independent** : $P(f.g>0)=P(A)\cdot P(B)+P(A^C)\cdot P(B^C) \qquad(1)$

> If events are **dependent** : $P(f.g>0)=P(A)\cdot P(B\mid A)+P(A^C)\cdot P(B^C\mid A^C)\qquad(2)$

**My question is**

In general, can we claim that $(2)$ is always less or equal than $1$?

Comment: $P(E) \leq 1$ for any event $E$. So $P(fg>0) \leq 1$ which implies that the right side of (2) is also less than or equal to $1$.

Comment: The title says "less and equal to $(1)$" but at the end of the question you write "less or equal than $1$". Did you mean to write $(1)$ again and simply forgot the parentheses?

Comment: Moreover even "$(2)$ is always less than or equal to $(1)$" would be ambiguous in this context. Is $(2)$ the entire equation? The right side only? The left side only?

Comment: Furthermore it seems you've already asked this question in a slightly different form and gotten a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Assume $f$ takes on value 1 and -1 with equal probability, and so does $g$.

When they are independent, probability (1) is 1/2.

When they are 100% dependent, say $f = g$, probability (2) is 1.